# "Waiting for device to come online". Running Android emulator from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I'm having a problem where my emulator cannot start and I get this message "waiting for device to come online". Try to quit the emulator but cannot quit until some time. This keeps happening to me with the same emulator. Any idea how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered in ["waiting for target device to come online" in Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757928/waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online-in-android-studio-2-3/44177992#44177992)

1. locate lib64 folder.Since i am running ubuntu 64 bit. In my case, its located under ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64.
2. In terminal, Navigate to the ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64 folder ,then run the following commands:

// Double Check to see if these are available

`$ sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386`

`$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

// then move the libstdc++ file inside the folder libstdc++.bak

`$ mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak`

// And execute below command

`$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++`