# "waiting for target device to come online" in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, emulation

Recently upgraded to Android Studio from 2.2.3 to 2., running on Win10

Emulator stopped working since then. Tried installing other images(25 rev 4)/upgrading for AVD but nothing seems to work. After running gradle and showing "waiting for target device to come online" in task bar nothing happens and program doesn't run.

Kindly help

---

Adding Screenshot:

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: Have you killed your adb ?

Comment: try to **invalidate cache and restart** from `File` menu

Comment: Already tried doing it... still no luck.

Comment: see another solution : [disable / enable adb integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730396/android-studio-emulator-wont-start-waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while waiting for device: Time out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675654/error-while-waiting-for-device-time-out-after-300seconds-waiting-for-emulator-t)

Comment: This may sound ridiculous but after hours of trying many SO solutions what worked for me was to completely remove Android Studio and reinstall without importing any settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458893/1159930

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I was also having the same issue 2 days ago when i update my android studio, today I solve my issue when I was playing around with settings then I saw that in my SDK tools setting **Android Emulator** is uncheck so I simply checked that box and now emulator is working fine.

Try this steps may work for you also:

1. Go to SDK tools > SDK Tools
2. Check **Android Emulator** and click Apply

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

There are changes, though it's installed, you might need to update

[image]

Comment: Fell back to using genymotion. Never got the built-in emulator to launch.

Comment: Haha! This simple fix worked for me. You'd think this would be downloaded and updated automatically by the system once the user creates an Android Virualization Device. Ridiculous! Had me running in circles.

Comment: Thanks dude. Updating Android Emulator solved the issue.

Comment: did not fix on 3.1.3

Comment: This fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 37):

I already have Emulator installed. But still had the same problem this morning with `Ubuntu 16.04` and `Android Studio 2.3`,Below is what I did and it worked.

Double Check to see if these are available:

```
    sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386    
    sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

1. Locate the lib64 folder. On Ubuntu 64 bit, its located under `~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64.`
2. In terminal, Navigate to the `~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64` folder ,then run the following commands:

move the libstdc++ file inside the folder libstdc++.bak and provide softlink

```
mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++
```

Comment: Following this answer solved the problem for me. No device was coming online after I upgraded to ubuntu 17.04 and at the same time I upgraded Android Studio to version 2.3.2.

Comment: Fixed issue and gets the +1, but an explanation of *why* this works and/or what the actual problem causing it is would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, this trick doesn't solve this problem in my case. 

Plus I have some doubts here. As of Android Studio 2.3.3 both of your mentioned dependencies **lib64stdc++6:i386** and **mesa-utils** are already there in the emulator directory - **~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/lib64stdc++** and **~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_mesa**.

The file on **~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/lib64stdc++** location is libstdc++.so.6. Why do I need to create symbolic links between these 2 location?

Comment: Neha Raj,  thank you very much,  the only solution that's worked for me.  One suggestion though.   However in my case all this had to be done in the ~/Android/emulator/lib64 directory.

Comment: Fixed the issue in Kali Linux 2017.1, Android Studio 2.3.3... Thanks!

Comment: This incomprehensible paganistic Linux blather solved my problem too!

Comment: Thanks it worked, can someone explain what did I do :)?

Comment: work for me on ubuntu17.04 with android studio 2.3.3, thanks a lot, a little more explaination would be more great

Comment: Thanks, not sure I would be able to figure this out without this answer :)

Answer (score 20):

None of these solutions worked for me.
After removing and installing the emulator from scratch several times, and also SDK Tools, I saw under developer options in the emulator that **USB debugging** was not active.

- Settings
- About Emulator Device
- Click several times on Build Number until it says that you are a developer
- Go back
- Get into developer options
- Put a check on "USB debugging"

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it worked for me and is quite an undocumented way

Comment: Additionally I needed to open Tools->AVD Manager and STOP the running emulator.  Then run the app and select the stopped emulator.  When it starts there should be a prompt to "allow USB debugging" - select yes.  That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 18):

if you docker is running you should close it.

Comment: I have tried by restarting my pc even. anything else i can try for?

Comment: Offical answer;

> You can't run software that uses another virtualization technology at the same time that you run the accelerated emulator. For example, VirtualBox, VMWare, and Docker currently use a different virtualization technology, so you can't run them at the same time as the accelerated emulator. 

[emulator-acceleration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#accel-vm)

Answer (score 11):

I realized my emulator was actually frozen, despite restarting it and restarting my computer. I just had to wipe data (AVD Manager > right-click on emulator > Wipe Data) and it started working again. You'll lose any state you had, but at least you won't have to reinstall it.

Answer (score 6):

First delete your exiting emulator than recreate it. Now run again hope it will fix your error.

Comment: deleted and recreated it... In fact downloaded other versions even to check if any issue with versions but still no changes... Emulator just dont come up.

Comment: Add screenshot for further assistance

Comment: added... pls ask for any more info :)

Comment: First time you're trying to running AVD? Try Genymotion Android Emulator, if it also won't working then update your Display driver or upgrade your PC.

Comment: No am not trying to run it for the first time... earlier it was working fine.. after i upgraded from android studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3 it stopped working.. and my os, display driver all is updated to latest versions. Is there is any way to log what is happening when it says **“waiting for target device to come online”**

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612468/how-can-i-get-more-information-about-waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online

Comment: No solution there and moreover its Linux based and am on Windows

Comment: Is there is anyway i can delete all emulator data and re install it without removing complete Android Studio as no solution seems to work...? I had tried removing adb ie virtual devices listed and removing and re downloading android images used for emulation...!!!

Comment: I recommend you install your new windows and reinstall it.

Comment: We need to be practical dude... just for trying an IDE if I have to reinstall everything then better leave it.... how come an IDE doesnt have option to track issue even... resolution is next...!!!

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same issue where the emulator would start up but I would be left with a black screen and my app won't load up.
Anyway, what I did was, I accessed the setting of the emulator. Make sure the "Save quick-boot state on exit for AVD Pixel_2_API_26" is set to "No". Note: My device is a Pixel 2, it could be different for other users.
 [image: Extended Controls]

Comment: How did you open up the settings? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Have a look at the bottom right corner of the photo. Those 3 dots, once you click them, it should open the Extended controls window and Select the Settings tab.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem ,I was using

> Linux LinuxRobot 4.14.0-kali3-amd64

and getting this

> host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm

and this message

> waiting for target device to come online

**Solution**
Close debugging and current emulator then

Open Avd Manager ,you will be able to see your device there then click on play button

[image]

**Or Try [Cold Boot](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3332/cold-boot)**

Open Android virtual device manager,click on drop button after select cold boot.
read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try configuring different Android Emulator and using it while running. You current emulator may have some issues. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when updated my android studio. Somehow it changed my SDK path. I just changed it to my updated SDK path and it worked.

Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK

Here you will find Android SDK location just click on edit link in front of that and browse and select the Android SDK from the file browser. Select and click on Apply.

Select AVD manager and start Emulator. This solution worked for me.

Comment: Rather than providing such a short answer, can you go into details of how the SDK can be changed?

Answer (score 1):

If none of the previous answers solved your problem, I suggest you to check KVM errors. Even if you did not install KVM it's possible you to get KVM errors when you try to run x86 images. Open a terminal and type `dmesg | grep kvm` after starting emulator. This way you will be able to see if you get KVM errors.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 machine with Android Studio 2.3.3 installed on it, the problem was about KVM. Android Studio was trying to enable KVM for x86 images. When I try to start the emulator, `dmesg` showing errors "kvm: enabling virtualization failed." Although ARM images were working fine.

After installing KVM, I was able to run x86 images on emulator without errors.

If this is the problem you are encountering, you might want to checkout [KVM installation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation).

Answer (score 1):

- first delete your AVD from tools>avd manager
- close android studio and restart computer
- open android studio click on run button on toolbar and click on *create new virtual device*  from there

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had another Android emulator running in the background, completely separate from Android Studio.  I saw it in the list when I loaded ADB, so it was detected for some reason, but I ignored it.  Anyway, when I closed it, this error went away and I was able to load my app no problem.  Specifically, I had BlueStacks loaded.  So, if you use BlueStacks or another Android emulator, close that as that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Click on App-->Edit configuration
[image]

choose "Specified activity".

[image]

Then in activity, choose your main activity(or whatever name you gave it), then click Ok.
[image]

Then in "target" choose "open select deployment target dialog".
[image]

Click "Apply" then "Ok".

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any solutions working and I tried almost every solution. What actually worked for me was something I accidentally stumbled upon. I opened two Android Studio applications and ran one and let it stay "waiting for target device to come online" and went to my other app that I want to run and run that but there will be an option under connected devices when you go to choose your avd, choose that one. It will connect to the avd you are using in the first app you ran and work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is having the issue now and non of the solutions worked. Try this:

I was having the same issue and it was actually caused by android Q preview. I created a device with Pie and everything just works.

Answer (score 1):

After trying Cold Boot and other stuff, I removed **Android Emulator** from **SDK Tools**, and then reinstalled. But first, I reinstalled **HAXM** too, because I recalled that I had an error message when installing by first time.

[image: HAXM error]

To install **HAXM** I had to disable **Hyper-V** on **Windows 10**, basically running:

`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

like stated here:
https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/105#issuecomment-430484231

After that, I reinstalled **Android Emulator**. It's just unchecking the box, applying the change, checking it again and applying the change. But you can follow more detailed steps here: https://www.technipages.com/android-emulator-stuck-waiting-for-target-to-come-online

After that, I have my AVD running.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of attempts, stopping device from AVD(exactly from AVD, not by cross button nor power off button on emulator) and starting build again helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Display driver ... this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you do not have SDK of your simulator,please check File->Settings->Appearance&Behavior->SystemSetting->Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn off Parallels Desktop and it started working again without reboot.

Answer (score 0):

For me what was happening was the Virtual device never booted.

What fixed this was:

```
cd ~/.android/avd/<Name of virtual device>/
rm *.img
```

Then I restarted the virtual device and it came on line.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing a “Cold Boot Now” in the device, but got an error saying: AVD Pixel_API_24 is already running. If that is not the case, delete the files at `/.android/avd/Pixel_API_24.avd/*.lock`.

After deleting a `.lock` file in the suggested folder the “Cold Boot Now” worked and the device was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the new update about `Quick boot`.

Unfortunately I had to disable it to make the emulator working again.

Android Studio -> tools -> Android -> AVD Manager -> edit your emulator -> Show Advanced Settings -> select Cold boot

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all my AVD files and recreated an AVD.

- (In windows), delete all files in `C:\Users\MyName\.android\avd\`
- Android Studio > Tools > AVD Manager > Create Virtual Device ...
- etc.

At this point in time I was on Win10, Android Studio 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved by modifying my configuration on AVD.

1) Go to the AVD Manager

2) Click "Edit this AVD" Button (the pencil icon).

I had no device selected and it showed an error message that I need to select a device for the AVD to work.  Once I did that and saved my emulator worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved a similar issue by enabling USB debugging under developer settings in the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the computer solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Setting the system variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to the path used by Android studio solved the issue for me:

- In Android Studio fire up Tools>Android>SDK Manager, navigate to
  Appearance & behavior>System Settings>Android SDK
- Copy the path from "Android SDK Location"
- Add ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to your system variables and assign the path
- Restart Android Studio