# "Waiting for target device to come online" Mac Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am trying to run my app through the virtual device but it says

> Waiting for target device to come online

and remains that way.I have seen so many people having this issue and general solution is exiting the Docker but I dont have Docker installed or any virtual device on My Mac.What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem by deleting the virtual device and setting it up again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Cool Boot** feacher of AVD Manage.

*For CoolBoot :*

1) Click on Tools > Android.

2) Click on AVD Manager.

3) Right click on target device then press to **Cool Boot Now**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was answered in ["waiting for target device to come online in Android Studio 2.3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757928/waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online-in-android-studio-2-3#42805346)

Try these steps:
Go to SDK Tools -> SDK Tools
Check **Android Emulator** and click Apply.

If that doesn't work try this:

Go to Tools -> Android -> then uncheck and recheck 'Enable ADB Integration'

Comment: Since I dont have Ubuntu on my system I dont know how to do the terminal part of the solution.First solution didnt work.

Comment: Can you try toggling the 'Enable ADB Integration' from Tools?

Comment: Didnt change anything.

Comment: Can you try launching the emulator from the command line? Navigate to the root of your SDK folder -> Tools and run `./emulator -list-avds` followed by `./emulator @name_of_avd -verbose`