# Android Emulator showing a error in Xamarin forms Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

Device error: adb.exe: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

This is the error that is popping up when i run the emulator.The emulator loads up and even the screen is on. The applications is seems not to be connecting to the emulator too

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=$ADB_VENDOR_KEYS+is+not+set+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Have you run the emulator well before? If you use it at first time, you should check the set up of the emulator first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [emulator broken: This adb server's $ADB\_VENDOR\_KEYS is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964674/emulator-broken-this-adb-servers-adb-vendor-keys-is-not-set)